# Issue with making migrations in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

Whenever I try to run `Add-Migration InitialMigration -StartupProject Infrastructure` I get this error.

> System.InvalidOperationException: No database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A provider can be configured by overriding the 'DbContext.OnConfiguring' method or by using 'AddDbContext' on the application service provider. If 'AddDbContext' is used, then also ensure that your DbContext type accepts a DbContextOptions object in its constructor and passes it to the base constructor for DbContext.

I guess my problem belongs to my file structure. I have 2 projects `Infrastructure` and `WebAPI`. In the `Infrastructure` I have DI file where I call `AddDbContext`.

```
public static IServiceCollection AddInfrastructure(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("ManagementRemote")
        ));

        return services;
    }
```

And here is my `program.cs`

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

    var configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);

    if (builder.Environment.IsDevelopment())
        configurationBuilder.AddUserSecrets<Program>();

    var configuration = configurationBuilder.Build();

    builder.Services
        .AddPresentation()
        .AddInfrastructure(configuration);

    var app = builder.Build();

    if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();

    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.MapControllers();

    app.Run();
```

I want to know how to deal with the error I have.

Comment: Show your `ApplicationDbContext` class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the project containing the aforementioned `Program.cs` as a parameter for `StartupProject`:

```bash
Add-Migration InitialMigration -StartupProject WebAPI
```

Possibly you might want to specify `-Project` parameter referencing the project with context.

Comment: But what if WebAPI doesn't reference the EF Core tools and design packages?

Comment: @JackFord then you might need to use [design-time factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dbcontext-creation?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#from-a-design-time-factory) in your `Infrastructure` project. Or just add the packages.